# Get last day of previous month that works for both Oracle AND SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, datetime

I am not sure this is possible. I need to write a query that can work on both Oracle and SQL Server. 
I am trying to get the last day of the previous month.

For instance, if it is December 17th, I would want November 30th.

I am aware of how to do them individually but can not figure out a way that works with both.

Comment: `SQL` doesn't mean *SQL Server*, Microsoft's brainwashing seems to work

Comment: I changed it to SQL server. Sorry I was brainwashed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

different DBMSs has different functions. SO you cannot expect to use same query on both SQL Server and Oracle

For SQL Server

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(d, -( DAY(GETDATE()) ), GETDATE())
```

For Oracle

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(yourdate,-1)) FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server (alt):

```
SELECT DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),0)-1
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the same method in a SQL that work unaltered both in Oracle and MS Sql Server?

The only way I'm seeing is to use a function that works the same in both.

For that you could create an EOMONTH function in the Oracle.
One that works the same as the existing [EOMONTH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql) function in MS Sql Server.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION EOMONTH (dt DATE, months SIMPLE_INTEGER DEFAULT 0) 
RETURN DATE IS
BEGIN
RETURN LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(dt, months));
END;
/
```

Then to get the last day of the previous month you can get the EOMONTH for -1 months in  both RDBMS:

```
SELECT EOMONTH(col, -1) AS EndOfPreviousMonth FROM yourtable
```

Oracle test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=945085a0aa3a8882da5a7713b4f463ce)*

MS Sql Server test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=ae18f8fdc900d067dfbbea74c6f2932e)*

Comment: @Riot And if adding a function to the Oracle isn't an option, then oh well, could still use the last_day & add_months / eomonth methods used.